# Passed argument does not match criteria

Tags: excel, argument-passing, vba

I tried to pass argument from one procedure to another. Everything looks ok, argument was passed, however it does match criteria given in `Select case` scenario.

What am I doing wrong?

Procedure passing argument:

```
Private Sub but_next_Click()

Call zmien_fakture("but_next")

End Sub
```

Procedure receiving argument:

```
Private Sub zmien_fakture(ByVal txt_name As String)

Select Case txt_name

    Case txt_name = "but_next"
        If Lastrow > nr_faktury_dol Then
            nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol + 1

        Else
            MsgBox ("To jest ostatnia faktura")

        End If

    Case txt_name = "but_prev"
        If nr_faktury_dol <> 1 Then: nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol - 1

    Case Else

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `Case txt_name = but_next` with `Case txt_name = "but_next"` and remove : in `If` condition since its a single line check

Comment: @PankajJaju Edited case as you advised = nothing changed. Not really understand why should I remove `if` condition... If given condition is true something happens if not it shows msgbox. How it would work without it?

Comment: Ahh my bad ... see simoco's answer ... you don't need to specify the variable in case conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Case txt_name = "but_next"` with `Case "but_next"`. Correct code is:

```
Private Sub zmien_fakture(ByVal txt_name As String)
    Select Case txt_name
        Case "but_next"
            If Lastrow > nr_faktury_dol Then
                nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol + 1
            Else
                MsgBox ("To jest ostatnia faktura")
            End If
        Case "but_prev"
            If nr_faktury_dol <> 1 Then: nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol - 1
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Why your syntax is not working:**

When you're using `Case txt_name = "but_next"`, statement `txt_name = "but_next"` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` and you get:

```
Select Case txt_name ' txt_name="but_next", but txt_name<>TRUE and txt_name<>FALSE
    Case True
        'do something
    Case False
        'do something
    Case Else
End Select
```

But in `Select Case txt_name` variable `txt_name` is NOT `True` or `False` and you actually jumps to `Case Else` part.

Alternative approach is to change `Select Case txt_name` to `Select Case TRUE` like this:

```
Private Sub zmien_fakture(ByVal txt_name As String)
    Select Case True
        Case txt_name = "but_next"
            If Lastrow > nr_faktury_dol Then
                nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol + 1
            Else
                MsgBox ("To jest ostatnia faktura")
            End If
        Case txt_name = "but_prev"
            If nr_faktury_dol <> 1 Then: nr_faktury_dol = nr_faktury_dol - 1
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It works great! I was looking everywhere just haven't thought that select case syntax is wrond. Thank you, again you are my argument-passing-saviour :)